# Syntax highliting rule to mark periods in between a method definition or invocation in Vim

Tags: javascript, regex, vim

I would like to know how to create a general highlighting rule in Vim to mark periods in between method invocations/definitions.

For example, I would like to see the period in this method invocation highlighted -> `obj.method()`. I would also like the rule to work with methods nested inside code blocks like this `obj.method([parameters...]) { anotherObj.anotherMethod() }`

[problem reproduced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQH7N.png)

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are you familiar with vim's syntax highlighting definitions in general?

Comment: Not too familiar. Someone was kind enough to give me this `hi MethodDot ctermfg=Red cterm=bold guifg=Red gui=bold                                    
syn match MethodDot "\(\w\)\@<=\.\(\w\)\@="` however, does not work inside code blocks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It makes dots bold/red, no matter whether they're surrounded by `{` `}` or not. Also, you don't need those parens: `syn match MethodDot /\w\@<=\.\w\@=/` works fine.

Comment: I added a link to an image that reprodruces the problem.

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce. All the dots are red on my end as well. Which probably means something else in your setup is blocking you. Try this: `vim -u NONE +'hi MethodDot ctermfg=Red cterm=bold guifg=Red gui=bold' +'syn match MethodDot /\w\@<=\.\w\@=/' test.js` to eliminate all other influences. If that works correctly, then do `vim test.js` and post the output of `:syn list` for debugging.

Comment: @Amadan I was able to grab output from `:syn list`. I have added it to a gist and here is the link -> https://gist.github.com/avocadoras/8ccee6ae31070885df3cdefad1afce33. Please help. EDIT: your suggestion worked so I followed the successful step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using something like `pangloss/vim-javascript` and not the default JavaScript syntax. If so, that syntax rather strictly defines what's allowed where. This should let your definition through the door:

```
:syn cluster jsExpression add=MethodDot
```

Comment: Thanks! It works very well. Where should I place this so that it persists?

Comment: Together with your snippet, in `.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim`.